# Best method to ensure Mysql master slave replication is consistent?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, master-slave

I am running a master slave replication system on AWS EC2 systems over ssh. However I came across a couple of best practice articles indicating that even this might allow inconsistencies to creep into the databases - I'd like to know what is the easiest way to ensure that both databases are consistent, and which would rectify any inconsistencies if they arose?

Answer (score 2):

The Percona Toolkit provides two tools to verify MySQL replication integrity and repair it if needed: pt-table-checksum and pt-table-sync. You can combine the first with some alert system like nagios and evaluate if a sync is safe. All the syncs by pt-table-sync are made on the master to keep consistency on the replication.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/